# Copy rows and increment column

Tags: mysql

I have a table that needs to have rows copied.  The table is such that there is a primary auto-incrementing key as well as a column used to group rows together.  Is there a way so that copying a series of rows that the group id is set to be incremented from the last value?

Here is basic example original table data

```
pri | grp
----------
1   | 1
2   | 9
3   | 2
4   | 1
5   | 2
6   | 9
7   | 2
```

My goal is to copy rows 1-7 and have a result like this:

```
pri | grp
----------
1   | 1
2   | 9
3   | 2
4   | 1
5   | 2
6   | 9
7   | 2
- copied -
8   | 10
9   | 12
10  | 11
11  | 10
12  | 11
13  | 12
14  | 11
```

Notice that the grp for the copied rows starts after the original Max grp, then increments by 1 for each new grp.

```
SET @new = (SELECT MAX(grp)+1 FROM tbl), @prev = (SELECT MIN(grp) FROM tbl);
INSERT INTO tbl (grp) (
SELECT IF(grp=@prev,
   -- set @prev, use @new
   , CASE
      WHEN (@prev:=grp) IS NULL THEN NULL
      ELSE @new
     END
   -- set @prev, update and use @new
   , CASE
      WHEN (@prev:=grp) IS NULL THEN NULL
      ELSE @new:=@new+1
     END)
FROM tbl
ORDER BY grp
)
```

This is giving me the following results, which looks like the @prev variable isn't being updated correctly.

```
pri | grp
----------
1   | 1
2   | 9
3   | 2
4   | 1
5   | 2
6   | 9
7   | 2
- copied -
8   | 10
9   | 14
10  | 11
11  | 10
12  | 12
13  | 15
14  | 13
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to allocate the new grp in a sub query and then order into the original order

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Tbl;
CREATE TABLE Tbl (PRI INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, GRP INT);
INSERT INTO Tbl (pri,grp) VALUES
(1   , 1),
(2   , 9),
(3   , 2),
(4   , 1),
(5   , 2),
(6   , 9),
(7   , 2);


INSERT INTO Tbl (grp) 
select  s.n
from
(
SELECT  t.pri tpri,t.grp tgrp
         ,if(t.grp <> @prev,@new:=@new+1,@new) n
         ,@prev:=t.grp p
FROM tbl t,(SELECT @new:= (select max(grp) from tbl),@prev:=0) n
order by t.grp
) s 
order by s.tpri
;

MariaDB [sandbox]> select * from tbl;
+-----+------+
| PRI | GRP  |
+-----+------+
|   1 |    1 |
|   2 |    9 |
|   3 |    2 |
|   4 |    1 |
|   5 |    2 |
|   6 |    9 |
|   7 |    2 |
|   8 |   10 |
|   9 |   12 |
|  10 |   11 |
|  11 |   10 |
|  12 |   11 |
|  13 |   12 |
|  14 |   11 |
+-----+------+
14 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```